# How to copy/repeat an array N times into a new array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have:

```
test = np.random.randn(40,40,3)
```

And I want to make:

```
result = Repeat(test, 10)
```

So that `result` contains the array `test` repeated 10 times, with shape:

```
(10, 40, 40, 3)
```

So create a tensor with a new axis to hold 10 copies of `test`. I also want to do this as efficiently as possible. How can I do this with Numpy?

Comment: If it meets your needs `np.repeat` is efficient.  Otherwise try `np.tile`.  `as_strided` can be more efficient, but it doesn't actually make copies.  `np.repeat(test[None], 10,0)`

Answer (score 20):

One can use [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) methods together with [`np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis):

```
import numpy as np

test = np.random.randn(40,40,3)
result = np.repeat(test[np.newaxis,...], 10, axis=0)
print(result.shape)
>> (10, 40, 40, 3)
```

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you're looking to copy the values 10 times, you can just [`stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) 10 of the array:

```
def repeat(arr, count):
    return np.stack([arr for _ in range(count)], axis=0)
```

`axis=0` is actually the default, so it's not really necessary here, but I think it makes it clearer that you're adding the new axis on the front.

---

In fact, this is pretty much identical to what the examples for `stack` are doing:

```
>>> arrays = [np.random.randn(3, 4) for _ in range(10)]
>>> np.stack(arrays, axis=0).shape
(10, 3, 4)
```

---

At first glance you might think [`repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) or [`tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) would be a better fit.

But `repeat` is about repeating over an existing axis (or flattening the array), so you'd need to `reshape` either before or after. (Which is just as efficient, but I think not as simple.)

And `tile` (assuming you use an array-like `reps`—with scalar `reps` it basically `repeat`) is about filling out a multidimensional spec in all directions, which is much more complex than what you want for this simple case.

---

All of these options will be equally efficient. They all copy the data 10 times over, which is the expensive part; the cost of any internal processing, building tiny intermediate objects, etc. is irrelevant. The only way to make it faster is to avoid copying. Which you probably don't want to do.

But if you do… To share row storage across the 10 copies, you probably want [`broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html):

```
def repeat(arr, count):
    return np.broadcast_to(arr, (count,)+arr.shape)
```

Notice that `broadcast_to` doesn't actually *guarantee* that it avoids copying, just that it returns some kind of readonly view where "more than one element of a broadcasted array may refer to a single memory location". In practice, it's going to avoid copying. If you actually need that to be guaranteed for some reason (or if you want a writable view—which is usually going to be a terrible idea, but maybe you have a good reason…), you have to drop down to [`as_strided`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html):

```
def repeat(arr, count):
    shape = (count,) + arr.shape
    strides = (0,) + arr.strides
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
        arr, shape=shape, strides=strides, writeable=False)
```

Notice that half the docs for `as_strided` are warning that you probably shouldn't use it, and the other half are warning that you definitely shouldn't use it for writable views, so… make sure this is what you want before doing it.

Comment: `broadcast_to` could probably manage the no-copy scenario as well, `np.broadcast_to(arr, (count,)+arr.shape)`.

Comment: @miradulo Good point. In fact, I think `broadcast_to` is basically a convenience function that's designed to make sure nobody ever uses `as_strided` for this use case…

Comment: I'm a fan of `stack`, but here `concatenate` is faster.  `stack` adds a dimension to each argument in the list.  It's faster to add that just once, do the list replication, and then concatenate.

Comment: @hpaulj But `concatenate` concatenates along an existing axis, rather than creating a new one. So it's the worst of both `repeat` (requiring a pre- or post-reshape) and `stack` (requiring explicitly passing 10 of arr) in one.

Comment: @hpaulj Unless you pass in `[[arr for _ in range(10)]]` instead of just `[arr for _ in range(10)]` to fake the extra axis, but then it's slower instead of faster. From a quick `%timeit`: `stack` takes 27.3us, `concatenate` with the wrong answer takes 23.6us, `concatenate` with the right answer takes 35.6us. Meanwhile, with an array 1000x the size, they're all around 17ms.

Answer (score 2):

Of the many ways of creating a proper copy, preallocation + broadcasting seems fastest.

```
import numpy as np

def f_pp_0():
    out = np.empty((10, *a.shape), a.dtype)
    out[...] = a
    return out

def f_pp_1():
    out = np.empty((10, *a.shape), a.dtype)
    np.copyto(out, a)
    return out

def f_oddn():
    return np.repeat(a[np.newaxis,...], 10, axis=0)

def f_abar():
    return np.stack([a for _ in range(10)], axis=0)

def f_arry():
    return np.array(10*[a])

from timeit import timeit

a = np.random.random((40, 40, 3))

for f in list(locals().values()):
    if callable(f) and f.__name__.startswith('f_'):
        print(f.__name__, timeit(f, number=100000)/100, 'ms')
```

Sample run:

```
f_pp_0 0.019641224660445003 ms
f_pp_1 0.019557840081397444 ms
f_oddn 0.01983011547010392 ms
f_abar 0.03257150553865358 ms
f_arry 0.02305851033888757 ms
```

But differences are small, for example `repeat` is hardly slower if at all.